# Why __getattr__ is called instead of catching AttributeError?

Tags: python, inheritance, attributeerror, getattr

I have implemented a simple lazy initialization in Python class:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print('__getattr__ was called!')

class Derived(Base):
    def GetValue(self):
        try:
            return self.val
        except AttributeError:
            self.val = 1
            return self.val

obj = Derived()
print(obj.GetValue())
```

I would like to catch an AttributeError when method GetValue() is called. In this example it doesn't happen, a method **getattr** is called. The method **getattr**() in Base class is mandatory and I cannot resign from using it. If it is possible I also don't want to resign of using try-except block. What could be a solution for this problem in Python 2.7?

Comment: Why *would* an attribute error be thrown if `__getattr__` is defined and doesn't throw one? What's the point of that method at all in your example?

Comment: The `GetValue` method is _not_ called anywhere.

Comment: I have changed my code to call a method GetValue().

Comment: jonrsharpe that is a solution for my problem, I have added raising an AttributeError in __getattr__() and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot resign from using the `__getattr__` method you have to manually throw the exception.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print('__getattr__ was called!')

        if not hasattr(self, item):
            raise AttributeError(self.__class__.__name__ +
                " instance has no attribute '" + item + "'")

class Derived(Base):
    def GetValue(self):
        try:
            return self.val
        except AttributeError:
            self.val = 1
            return self.val

obj = Derived()
print(obj.GetValue())
```